# PrimeNG Table [rowHovered] not working on cells where the cell-background is set

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

I have a scrollable [TreeTable](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/treetable) with the `rowHover`-attribute defined like this:

```
<p-treeTable [value]="items" [columns]="scrollableCols" [resizableColumns]="true" [frozenColumns]="frozenCols" [scrollable]="true" scrollHeight="550px" frozenWidth="600px" [rowHover]="true" *ngIf="submitFinished">
```

So I set the background of the second and third columns - I do this like this:

```
<td style="text-align: center; height: 40px" [ngStyle]="{'background-color' : (col.field=='diff') ? ((getColumnValue(rowData, columns, i) > 0) ? 
                '#e2fee2' : ((getColumnValue(rowData, columns, i) < 0) ? '#ffa695' : 'white') ) : 'white'}"> <!-- this code only applies on each 2nd and 3rd column, not the first one. The second is always white, the third is either #ffa695, #e2fee2 or white - the first still has its default value -->
```

This works out completely fine, sadly the `rowHover` is not only hovering the cells where I did not change the background. Is there a chance to avoid this and still hover the complete row? It is fine if you cannot see the colored background while the row hovers.

[image]

Edit:

I assume that it does that because applying the `[ngStyle]` "keeps tracking" the value of the field and then applies the color to it, so even the selection from `rowHover` should be overridden. Sadly I have no idea how to work around that.

This is what I would like it to look like: (example created by not applying `[ngStyle]` of the `<td>` mentioned above)

[image]

Still, the code if it helps:

The full scrollable body (where it should apply):

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData="rowData" let-columns="columns">
    <tr *ngIf="!rowData.hours"><td *ngFor="let col of columns" style="height: 60px" class="psp-row-cell"></td></tr>
    <tr *ngIf="rowData.hours">
      <ng-template ngFor let-i="index" let-col [ngForOf]="columns">
        <ng-template [ngIf]="rowDataIsEmpty(rowData, col)" [ngIfElse]="editableColumn">
          <td class="blocked-cell" style="height: 40px">
          </td>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template #editableColumn>
          <ng-template [ngIf]="col.field=='plan'" [ngIfElse]="blockedCell">
              <td style="text-align: center; height: 40px" [ttEditableColumn]="rowData"> 
                  <p-treeTableCellEditor>
                      <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                          <input pInputText type="text" style="text-align: center" [ngModel]="getColumnValue(rowData, columns, i)" (ngModelChange)="setColumnValue(rowData, columns, i, $event)" [ngStyle]="{'width':'100%'}">
                      </ng-template>
                      <ng-template pTemplate="output">{{getColumnValue(rowData, columns, i)}}</ng-template>
                  </p-treeTableCellEditor>
                </td>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template #blockedCell>
            <td style="text-align: center; height: 40px" [ngStyle]="{'background-color' : (col.field=='diff') ? ((getColumnValue(rowData, columns, i) > 0) ? 
                '#e2fee2' : ((getColumnValue(rowData, columns, i) < 0) ? '#ffa695' : 'white') ) : 'white'}"> 
              {{getColumnValue(rowData, columns, i)}}
            </td>
          </ng-template>
        </ng-template>
      </ng-template>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
```

The getColumnValue:

```
getColumnValue(rowData: any[], columns: any, i: number): number {
    let col = columns[i];
    let val;
    if (col.field == 'diff') {
      col = columns[i-2];
      val = rowData['hours'].find(entry => entry.year === col.year && entry.month === col.month)[col.field];
      col = columns[i-1];
      val = val - rowData['hours'].find(entry => entry.year === col.year && entry.month === col.month)[col.field];
    } else {
      val = rowData['hours'].find(entry => entry.year === col.year && entry.month === col.month)[col.field];
    }
    return val;
  }
```

Comment: Please show fully HTML and getColumnValue function

Answer (score 1):

As assumed, the `background-color` seems to be overriden by the `[ngStyle]` when changed by `rowHover`. One workaround was to simply change the `white` back to `transparent`, so:

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-color' : (col.field=='diff') ? ((getColumnValue(rowData, columns, i) > 0) ? 
            '#e2fee2' : ((getColumnValue(rowData, columns, i) < 0) ? '#ffa695' : 'transparent') ) : 'transparent'}
```

which is kind of working for this problem.